# Facebook API: Retrieving likes results only in {"data":[]}

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

I'm trying to check if the logged user likes a certain page, but the resulting string is

```
{"data":[]}
```

as in, it retrieved nothing... What's the problem? I can retrieve the user info just fine, but when I try anything related to likes, I get this.

Just for clarity's sake, I'm calling it like this:

```
FB.API("/me/likes/(mypageidhere)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,Teste);
```

I tried putting the user id directly instead of /me, as well as using just /me/likes, same error.

Comment: And do you have `user_likes` permission? (Btw., you will not get that granted in review for such a purpose. Like gating is not allowed any more.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this will occur when you don't have `user_likes` permission set. You can check for this with `/me/permissions`. The other scenario is that the user doesn't like the page being queried, recheck to ensure you have the correct ID.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I thought that the public profile one was enough since it wasn't giving me a proper error.